# Del. and r/w linked List Nodes in Multithreading with RW-locks -> deadlocks?

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, thread-safety, pthreads

I've got a question about how exactly rw-locks in multithreading working with single linked lists.

First of all the Scenario in a Pitcure:

```
    Head ==> A ==> B ==> C ==> Tail
                   ^    
                  | |
                  |  ----------> Thread 2:
            Thread 1:            - rw-access B    
            -deleting B
```

And now in text; Thread 1 is on the way to deleting Node B so locks A and locks B after locking to B is done, Thread 2 is trying to read or/and write information to/from B so he`s is trying to lock B and hate to wait, because Thread 1 already locked B.

Now I'm a little bit confused
**What happens after Thread 1 deleted B and unlocks B?**
**Is Thread 1 in a deadlock, because I deleted the Lock in B by using free(b) ?**
**Do I have to destroy the Lock for B in Thread 1 ?**
**Do I have to manage this case in a routine? like: Check after getting the lock if B is still a Node ?**
Here another "picture" to illustrate it.

```
Thread 1                Thread 2
----------------------  ----------------------
Lock A                  
Lock B                         
A->next = C;            Lock B
Unlock A                waiting ...
free(B)                 waiting ...
Unlock B                waiting ...
                        Get Lock B
                        Try to read/write B  // what happens now?
```

My List elements looks like this

```
typedef struct Node
{
    char Name[21];          // Information Dummy
    pthread_rwlock_t aLock; // rw lock
    Node *next;             // pointer to the next node
}Node;
```

I hope I were able to illustrate my Problem ;)

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert/delete list nodes, then doing fine-grained synchronization without locking the whole list is a bit tricky. The best way to start is to look through the slides from Maurice Herlihy & Nir Shavit: "[Linked Lists: Locking, Lock-Free, and Beyond ...](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall05/G22.2631-001/lists.slides2.pdf)".

I also strongly recommend the classical work "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" from the same authors, this is the must-read book if you are seriously interested in multithreading.

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment and the book tip, I did a little bit of research in your recommended literature and nearly none of my questions are answered, but I've learned some new stuff I like to know ;)